# Problem when graphing sine waves in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, sine-wave

I've written the following program using python in order to graph multiple sine waves of different frequencies, as well as display the points of intersection between them;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

f1 = float(input("Enter first frequency: "))
f2 = float(input("Enter second frequency: "))
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t)
y2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*t)

plt.plot(t,y1, color = "firebrick", label = "sin({}Hz)".format(f1))
plt.plot(t,y2, color = "teal", label = "sin({}Hz)".format(f2))
plt.axhline(y = 0, color = "grey", linestyle = "dashed", label = "y = 0")

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2))).flatten()
plt.plot(t[idx], y1[idx], 'k.')

plt.legend(loc = "best", frameon=True, fancybox = True,
           shadow = True, facecolor = "white")

plt.axis([-0.5, 10.5, -1.5, 1.5])

plt.title("Sine Waves")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")

plt.show()
```

Sometimes the output looks just as it's supposed to, for example
[in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYlU2.jpg).
However, at other times i obtain an undesired output such as [in this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXTie.jpg). 
Could someone demonstrate how to fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to increase your time discretization or simply plot these waves in terms of number of `n_T` periods of the highest/lowest frequency to avoid undersampling problems. For instance, if you more interested in the lowest frequency you could modified your code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

f1 = float(input("Enter first frequency: "))
f2 = float(input("Enter second frequency: "))

n_T = float(input("Enter number of periods of lowest frequency to display: "))
t_max = n_T/min(f1,f2) # change here max or min if you want highest or lowest frequency to be represented on n_T periods

t = np.linspace(0, t_max, 1000)

y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t)
y2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*t)

plt.plot(t,y1, color = "firebrick", label = "sin({}Hz)".format(f1))
plt.plot(t,y2, color = "teal", label = "sin({}Hz)".format(f2))
plt.axhline(y = 0, color = "grey", linestyle = "dashed", label = "y = 0")

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2))).flatten()
plt.plot(t[idx], y1[idx], 'k.')


plt.legend(loc = "best", frameon=True, fancybox = True,
           shadow = True, facecolor = "white")

plt.axis([-0.05*t_max, 1.05*t_max, -1.5, 1.5])

plt.title("Sine Waves")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")

plt.show()
```

which gives for `n_T=3` and `f1=200` and `f2=400` Hz :

[image: 1]

and for your problematic case `f1=520` and `f2=750` Hz:

[image: 2]

***BONUS*** : if you want to compute automatically the minimum number `n_T` of periods to display the exact number of unique intersections  between the two oscillating components. First, convert user inputs `f1` and `f2` from floats to integers, then find the lowest common multiple `lcm` between them (using greatest common divisor `gcd` function from `math`) and divide it by the highest frequency, here you are:

```
from math import gcd
def lcm(a,b):
    """
    Compute the lowest common multiple of a and b
    """
    return a*b/gcd(a,b)

# minimum of n_T periods to visualize every unique intersections of waves
n_T = lcm(f1,f2)/max(f1,f2)
```

for instance for `f1=250` and `f2=300` Hz, `n_T=1500/300=5` which will give:

[image: bonus]

Comment: fantastic, thanks! However i don't understand what n_T refers to. For example, what difference is made when the value is changed? What possible values can it be?

Comment: It's just the number of periods you want to display: here you can see that with `n_T=3` there is exactly three waves of the lowest frequency, in each case it corresponds to the red plot, change that number as you want, it can be a positive float but I prefer it to be a positive integer :). Is that clear?

Comment: Ohh alright i see. Yes i understand now. I appreciate it.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you.